# How to add path field to every document in an ElasticSearch index?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, logstash

While pushing logs from local to ES using file input plugin, a `path` field gets added which contains the actual path of the log file which the document was created from.
But this field doesn't show up when using the AWS `s3` input plugin. How do I add it?

My s3 input plugin:

```
s3 {
      "access_key_id" => "***"
      "secret_access_key" => "***"
      "backup_to_dir" => "/home/xyz/aws_s3_backup_data/"
      "bucket" => "bucket"
      "prefix" => "folder/dir/"
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looks like](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-s3/issues/104#issuecomment-304310166) they added it as `[@metadata][s3][key]`, though it's not in the documentation.